# Weird behavior when shift left

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have an incredible simple equation but for some reason I just cannot get it right.

```
#include "iostream"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    uint64_t shamt = 0x0;
    uint64_t mask = 0xffffffffffffffff;

    printf("mask << (64 - shamt): %016lx\n", mask << (64 - shamt));

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the printf yields 0, but it's actually unchanged. The weird thing is, if I represent shamt = 0 (decimal instead of uint), the behavior is correct.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: For me, the output is correct: "mask << (64 - shamt): 0000000000000000", maybe it's an UB?

Comment: `printf` requires `#include<stdio.h>` and `uint64_t` requires `#include<stdint.h>`. If it happens to compile without them, then this is coincidence. Standard headers should also be included with the `<>` syntax, not the `""` one.

Comment: [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators): "if the value of the right operand is negative or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined." That is, shifting `std::uint64_t` by 64 bits is UB.

Comment: @Evg Huh. You are right. Everyone is correct actually. It is an undefined behavior and I tried with a smaller shift amount, it works.

Comment: For a 64-bit integer, the shift amount must be between 0 (inclusive) and 63 (inclusive).  Looks like yours is shifting by 64, which is too much.